# fail2ban not banning, time is off, how do I sync them?

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

In searching for why fail2ban is not banning patterns, I found
that when I run /etc/init.d/fail2ban status it reports over an
hour behind my 'date' command.

'date' says its: Tue Mar 18 20:45:02 MST 2014

Output of status returns:
Mar 05 19:16:30 fed8 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start/Stop fail2ban...

I know my 'date' is correct, why is fail2ban not in sync and
how do I fix that?  Is there a config option to force it to
get the unix command 'date' instead?

Im using fail2ban 8.12
Thanks

EDIT:
Added patch from bug report, didnt change things.  I should have included the
full output.  The date is way off as well, almost 2 weeks old? Why is that?
It seems the status isnt reporting whats going on the last time I tried to
start it?  When I do a ps I see that the fail2ban-server is indeed 'running':

```
root     26430  0.4  0.1 1268652 14820 ?       Sl   21:58   0:01 /usr/bin/python    /usr/bin/fail2ban-server -b -s /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock -p /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid -x


/etc/init.d/fail2ban status
fail2ban.service - LSB: Start/Stop fail2ban
Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/fail2ban)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2014-03-05 19:26:00 MST; 1 weeks 6 days ago
Main PID: 1145 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
CGroup: name=systemd:/system/fail2ban.service

Mar 05 19:16:30 fed8 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start/Stop fail2ban...
Mar 05 19:16:33 fed8 fail2ban[945]: Starting fail2ban: ERROR  No section: 'Definition'
Mar 05 19:16:33 fed8 fail2ban[945]: ERROR  No section: 'Definition'
Mar 05 19:16:38 fed8 fail2ban[945]: [  OK  ]
Mar 05 19:16:38 fed8 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start/Stop fail2ban.
Mar 05 19:26:00 fed8 fail2ban[3481]: Stopping fail2ban: ERROR  Unable to contact server.    Is it running?
Mar 05 19:26:00 fed8 fail2ban[3481]: [FAILED]
Mar 05 19:26:00 fed8 systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: control process exited, code=exited status=255
Mar 05 19:26:00 fed8 systemd[1]: Unit fail2ban.service entered failed state.
```

e

EDIT2:
I found that I needed to use 'system fail2ban start' rather than using the
command line.  This fixed the status reporting.  The fail2ban log file correctly
shows the startup time in sync with the 'date' command now, however it's still not
banning.  I ran fail2ban-regex on the last pattern I saw in my file and it should
have picked it up but did not.

EDIT3:  I still cant figure out why it wont ban patterns.  fail2ban-regex is catching
my patterns properly when I run it manually.  The only other thing I found in another
post is that someone suggested running 'system iptables status' which produced:

```
163 ROOT fed8 /etc/fail2ban service iptables status
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  iptables.service
iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
       start condition failed at Sun 2014-03-23 18:23:40 MST; 3s ago

Mar 23 18:23:40 fed8 systemd[1]: Started IPv4 firewall with iptables.
```

Now my question is, if this is the reason its not running, WHY?  isnt iptables
just called directly by fail2ban to ban/unban stuff?  Ive never run iptables
as a service.  I run it directly out of /etc/rc.local.  If this isnt the issue,
can anyone tell me why this thing fails to ban??  Im beginning to wonder if its not
easier to write my own banning program so at least I know I can count on it rather
than having to check that this thing is still catching patterns from day to day!
So frustrating.  I got other work to do than babysit fail2ban.  Im quickly losing
faith in it.

Comment: That's not "more than an hour" - that's "more than 13 days"...

Comment: Yes I realized that after I posted which is why I reposted more data.

Comment: What Linux distribution is this? What are you running it on?

Comment: Are you running ntpd?  Run `ntpq -pcrv` and make sure it's syncing.

Comment: Fedora 18, 64 bit

Comment: Sorry, didnt answer the ntpd question because the times are in sync now.  Still not catching patterns though.

Comment: I debugged similar issues on my server, UTC server btw.
Fail2ban detected times that were wrong between 1 hour and 3.5 hours, random wrong times.
It's python so I did not invest my nerves into hunting that bugs down but while I had these issues I discovered other problems, including race conditions with iptables.

The software is absolutely horrible

Answer (score 1):

It looks alot like a configuration issue.  The specific error message is:

> Mar 05 19:16:33 fed8 fail2ban[945]: Starting fail2ban: ERROR  No
>   section: 'Definition'

So, the next step is to find out what file is being used as a configuration file by fail2ban, which appears to typically be in /etc/fail2ban, possibly starting in jail.conf (it looks as though it might have a multi-file configuration).

Having found the configuration, you would work out why, in the course of parsing the configuration, the program fails to find a section named "Definition" that it expects and apparently requires.

The date you see in the `/etc/init.d/fail2ban status` command output is the last time the program functioned correctly, not the current date from the perspective of the program.